# What are the minimum specifications to run OneSignal?

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, onesignal

Although I found the cause of the problem, but I am looking for a solution for it.

I recently added OneSignal to the project and it no longer works on Android 4.4

because of it when I delete the Signal.class file definition from Manifests, the project works

Is there a solution to make it work with the plugin?

```
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="com.abo3bdo.m3rag.Signal">
    <activity android:name="com.abo3bdo.m3rag.MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.abo3bdo.m3rag.Web_Activity" />
    <activity android:name="com.abo3bdo.m3rag.home_main">
```

signal class

```
package com.abo3bdo.m3rag;

import android.app.Application;

import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

public class Signal extends Application {
    private static final String ONESIGNAL_APP_ID = "*****";
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable verbose OneSignal logging to debug issues if needed.
    OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);

        // OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.initWithContext(this);
        OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID);
    }
}
```

Gradle

```
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'
```

Comment: In fact, it requires Android 4.0.3 according to its official website, but why does it not work for me on Android  4.4

Comment: I would include more details about what doesn't work on Android 4.4. I would check the logcat in Android Studio for any errors or warnings and share that here as well.

Comment: I have test The OneSignal SDK 4.4.0 and the Android Studio Android 4.4 emulator it was able to register and display notifications correctly.

Comment: I'm confused because I tried it on Android 5.0 and it works without problems, but on Android 4.4 it doesn't work, unless I delete the signa.class